# iOS - Video playing gives errors

Tags: iphone, video

When I follow [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cYXAHRvHbQE), it gives me an error on the `[playercontroller release];` line, so I remove it, and then it gives me [these errors](http://aftermathgame.webs.com/Screen+Shot+2012-07-09+at+2.13.05+PM.png) when I try to run it.

I tried making another app to test the video, and it works seamlessly, but it will not work in my main app. Can anyone help?

And when I reimported the framework, and tried to play the video, it gives me this error:

`2012-08-17 11:27:03.174 LYWAM Tour[768:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1e15022 0x10fdcd6 0x1dbda48 0x1dbd9b9 0xba253b 0xba24c5 0x54ac 0x1e16e99 0x26314e 0x2630e6 0x309ade 0x309fa7 0x308d8a 0x2882cf 0x2885e6 0x26edc4 0x262634 0x16f7ef5 0x1de9195 0x1d4dff2 0x1d4c8da 0x1d4bd84 0x1d4bc9b 0x16f67d8 0x16f688a 0x260626 0x24cd 0x2435 0x1)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)`

Comment: "it gives me an error on the [playercontroller release]" -- what error? Always give us the error output.

Comment: Also, is your main app using ARC or not? If it uses ARC, you shouldn't be calling release, retain, or autorelease anywhere in your project.

Comment: I edited the post, I reimported the framework, and the build succeeded, but now I have another problem.

Comment: Ok, if you're using ARC, it makes no sense to have a release in your code. The demo you're copying from seems to not be using ARC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take it `GVE1ViewController` is a class you wrote yourself? Does it definitely implement a method called `GrommeVideoExcerpt1`? Is what you assigned to the variable actually an instance of `GVE1ViewController` (or a subclass?) Put in an NSLog to check that it really is an instance of `GVE1ViewController`.

To do the NSLog, you need a line of the form:

```
NSLog(@" My controller = %@", myVar);
```

where `myVar` is whatever variable you have containing a reference to the `GVE1ViewController`.

Comment: I am still in the learning process, and trying to figure out how this works, so im sorry for the dumb question, but how do you put in an NSLog?

Comment: So it would be `NSLog(@" My controller = %@", GrommeVideoExcerpt1);`?
And where exactly would I put this?

Comment: Hi Alan, it seems from your level of knowledge that you need to learn the basics of objective C a bit more thoroughly. It's not really possible to run someone through that level of stuff on SO -- it's really down to you to learn the basics of the language. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for accepting, hope you get to the bottom of it (or maybe already have).